# Pass all output variables between stages in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to pass multiple variables between stages in Azure DevOps. I have created variables within a loop using the following code:

```py
for variable, value in args.vars:
    print(f'##vso[task.setvariable variable={variable};isOutput=true]{value}')
```

The variables are created successfully, and I can see them via `env`. Now, I want to add these variables to another stage without explicitly referencing their names. If possible, I would like to add all variables output in this step to another stage.

I have tried to do this in a loop, but it seems that in azure-pipelines-yaml files, this is not allowed:

```yaml
variables:
  ${{ each variable in dependencies.TEST.CREATE_VAR.outputs['MYVAR_CREATION'] }}:
    ${{ variable.key }}: ${{ variable.value }}
```

Comment: `##vso[task.setvariable]` is a *runtime* variable. Anything enclosed in `${{}}` is a **compile-time** expression, which occurs *before* runtime and thus runtime variables **do not exist yet**. You can't use runtime variables in compile-time expressions, end of story.

Comment: Okay I see normally I would do something like ‘‘‘variables:
    curProjVersion1: $[ dependencies.Build.VersionCheck.outputs['setCurProjVersion.curProjVersion'] ]‘‘‘ but I don’t want to add each variable manually. If possible I would like to just get all variables created via the vso statement

Comment: Yes, that's a runtime expression. Runtime expressions are significantly more limited.